# Nested React Router : hide parent component on showing nested child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Being a beginner in reactJS, I want to know how to hide parent component when i route to child component URL

**Assume a scenario:**

User is at "/house" as this:

```
<Route path="/house" component={House} />
```

[image]

when user clicks a house grid he navigates to "/house/flat/:flatID". Inside House component

```
<Route
    path={`${this.props.match.url}/flat/:flatId`}
    render={() => <div>Each Flat details</div>}
/>
```

then both child and parent components are visible like this: 
[image]

So what i want is to show only flat component when user navigates to "/house/flat:FlatId". Please suggest me anything that helps ! Any links to article so that i can learn and achieve such functionality.

**Code:**

*App.js*

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route exact path="/account" component={Account} />
    <Route path="/gharjagga" component={GharJagga} />
</Switch>
```

*House.js*

```
onGharGridClick= id => {
    <Redirect to={`${this.props.match.url}/flat/${id}`} />;
};

return (
    <Route
        path={`${this.props.match.url}/flat/:fkatId`}
        render={() => <div>Ghar Each</div>}
    />
);
```

Comment: You want switch route right? Or Please share you route s code

Comment: when user clicks any grid he navigates to /house/flat/flatID then what i want to show in this url is only flat details, instead both House and flat Details are showing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can achieve it different ways

1. define routes in the parent component, I think this is the best option.

```js
<Switch>
  <Route path="/account" component={Account} />
  <Route path="/house/flat/:flatId" component={FlatComponent}/>
  <Route path="/house" component={House} />
  <Route path="/" component={Home} />
</Switch>
```

*Note: instead of using `exact`, order your routes based on priority, that will make the route to redirect to next matching route if any typo in the route entered*

2. You can make House as separate route component, and nest the routes inside that component

```js
// Routes
<Switch>
  <Route path="/account" component={Account} />
  <Route path="/house" component={House} />
  <Route path="/" component={Home} />
</Switch>

// House component
class House extends React. Components {
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/house/flat/:flatId" render={() => <div>Each Flat details</div>} />}/>
        <Route path="/house" component={HouseGridComponent} />
      </Switch>
    )
  }
}
```

3. you can check whether the route has `flatId` and hide the elements, in your House component you can check `this.props.match.params.flatId`, if the `flatId` is set you can hide that House Component.

```js
// House Component

class House extends React. Components {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          !this.props.match.params.flatId?
            <h1>House Component</h1>:
            null
        } 

        <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}/flat/:flatId`} render={() => <div>Each Flat details</div>} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: ok i got what you are trying to convey ! but when house component is rendered, i fetch all the data and when user clicks any grid (house) then the data of that house has to be passed into the flat component , do you understand my scenario?

Comment: so i cant fetch the data from parent component ! and i have to pass props to flat from house

Comment: You can use second option for that

Comment: is this the best options ? aren't there any solutions to only route to the child component only instead of both parents and child component

Comment: Try the new second option that would be much better, also best practice, I forgot to add that before

Comment: I think, according to react-router documentation, whenever you want to use `match` in a `Route` component, you should use `match.path` and if you want to use it in a `Link` component, use `match.url`. This is because `match.path` will give you a path like `/:paramId/...` and `match.url` will give you a complete URL like `localhost:3000/some-id`.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you <3 <3 <3 :D

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to raise `"/house/flat/:flatId"` to the same level as `"/house"`.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/account" component={Account} />
  <Route path="/house/flat/:flatId" render={() => <div>Each Flat details</div>}/>
  <Route path="/house" component={House} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: but i want to pass the props from House component to Flat Component as well , and thanks for this ! very close to the solutions

Comment: You'll have to store and retrieve the data in/from a common ancestor. See [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) for more info @EfrainSanjayAdhikary

Comment: they both are inside app.js ! isn't it be too heavy to load everything in app.js and shared into flat and House.

Comment: Nah, the overhead is negligible. You could alternatively nest `"/"` and `"/flat/:flatId"` subroutes within `"/house"` if you want to manage the `state` in a purer manner. The fundamental steps/logic are the same either way @EfrainSanjayAdhikary